# Why is my SharePoint site still caching an old javascript library I stopped using?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server

I have copy and pasted a html form with libraries attached being linked in embedded code. I've gotten rid of all references to one library but I'm still getting the following error:

```
(Internal Server Error)

/Scripts/JScript1.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

This is no longer referenced. My other errors also reference the old javascript file that I no longer imported. I even deleted everything from the page at one point and it still wouldn't work.

I have tried pasting the html and then the javascript into a new page but for some reason it is still not working.

Comment: are you sure the javascript file isn't being referenced from the masterpage?

Comment: I've never done anything on the master pages so I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to publish the page that throws that error. Once done, clean your cache and try again! (Or access the page using the incognito mode)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. Incognito is disabled where I work, so can't try that or any other browser unfortunately